# Delimited \def's and expansion

Tags: expansion, programming

I try to understand how work the macro named `\separator` in `MWE` .

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\def\separator#1\separator#2{%
\unexpanded{#1}%
\ifx*#2%
\else
, \expandafter\separator\expandafter#2%
\fi
}%



    \def\stcs{\separator One\separator Two\separator three}

    \tracingmacros 1
    \begin{document}

    \stcs\separator*

    \end{document}
```

### Trace of `\separator` is following:

```
\stcs ->\separator One\separator Two\separator three

\separator #1\separator #2->\unexpanded {#1}\ifx *#2\else , \expandafter \separator \expandafter #2\fi 
#1<-One
#2<-T

\separator #1\separator #2->\unexpanded {#1}\ifx *#2\else , \expandafter \separator \expandafter #2\fi 
#1<-Two
#2<-t

\separator #1\separator #2->\unexpanded {#1}\ifx *#2\else , \expandafter \separator \expandafter #2\fi 
#1<-three
#2<-*
```

### What have I see.

**At the first stage:**

---

First: `\separator` gets  a `#1` as 'One' -this is normal for me.
Second: `\separator` gets  a `#2` only 'T' but not 'Two'. Why?

**At the second stage:**

---

First: `\separator` gets  a `#1` as 'Two'. Why not 'T', as one can see from the first stage? And what had become of this 'T'? It lost?

`\LaTeX` pdf output is normal "One, Two, three".
Thus, what is happen with `#2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#1` is a *delimited* argument that consists of all tokens up to the specified delimiter, `\separator` here. LaTeX doesn't really support the definition of such arguments (hence the use of `\def` rather than `\newcommand`.

`#2` is a normal non-delimited argument. So this takes a single token or `{}` group.
In the case you trace it just gets `T` just as if you go `\fbox abc`  the argument of `\fbox` is just `a`.

`#2` is just used for testing and if you are not at the end it is put back here:

```
\expandafter\separator\expandafter#2%
```

so when that `\separator` is expanded it sees

`Two\separator three`

in the input stream The `T` having been put back, so takes `Two` as `#1` and `t` as `#2` and the loop continues.

Comment: What does it mean "put back"? It is in the `stack` or what?

Comment: @sergiokapone tex is a macro expansion language, not a compiled program, the engine works on a stream of tokens, if first token is expandable then it is replaced in the stream by its expansion then processing re-starts at the (new) start of the stream

Comment: as I read about `\expandafter` the token #2 is saved without expansion, because it is immediately after `\expandafter`. Why is it needed?

Comment: @sergiokapone If `#2` is one token then the `\expandafter` chain will expand the `\fi`, closing the conditional and making the code tail recursive. If `#2` isn't one token then this fails to do anything useful (won't be an issue in a lot of cases).

Comment: @Joseph Wright as I understand you, the  second `\expandafter` LaTeX consider as `\expandafter#2\fi` and an expansion of `\fi` is just a closing a condition. Am I correct?

Comment: @sergiokapone yes but the expansion of `\fi` is nothing and that is important if you expanded the \separator without doing this it would not see `Two` as its `#1` but `T\fi wo` you need the `\fi` to be removed before recursing to look for the next item.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, it seems to me, I understand what happens.